# How to fill empty columns in csv with NA values without using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to fill the empty columns of csv file with 'NA'. I am able to do it using pandas. But i dont want to use pandas. How can i do it while writing into csv without using pandas?

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
import csv
import time
import pandas as pd

index = []
time_stamp = []
image_link_list = []

for i in range(5):
    i += 1
    index.append(i)
    time_stamp.append(int(time.time()))

compilation = [index, image_link_list, time_stamp]
data_collection = zip_longest(*compilation, fillvalue='')

with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    csv_header = csv_writer.writerow(['ID', 'IMAGE_LINK', 'TIME_STAMP'])
    csv_rows = csv_writer.writerows(data_collection)    
    csv.fillna()
```

Please help me correct over the code.

Comment: Start with `data_collection = zip_longest(*compilation, fillvalue='NA')`. If you have empty columns elsewhere, you will probably want to loop over `data_collection` and manually replace empty strings with "NA". You haven't shown your data here, so it isn't immediately clear whether that is necessary or not.

Comment: I should probably also ask the obvious question: "why _not_ pandas?" Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Firstly thanks. It works! Well, why not pandas, the image_link_list is empty. Ok let me try that and get back.

Comment: Done with pandas. thanks cs95